# Using Xcode, how do you jump to a definition in counterpart view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I use the counterpart view a lot in Xcode 4 to have my header files open along side my .m files.  If you right-click, command-click, etc on the method names in the header file it will jump to the definition in that same view window.  I'd rather it take me to the method in the counterpart window that already has the definition in it.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you command-option-click on a symbol, its declaration will be opened in the other (counterpart) editor.

Answer (score 1):

The Option key transfers most navigation operations to the counterpart view, so to jump to a definition in the counterpart view use Command+Option+Click.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I only accepted the other due to its "first"-ness.